# Get Distance From CLProximity

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, proximity

i am developing a beacon detecting app using objective c and i am getting beacon value as follow

```
CLBeacon (uuid:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x174223ee0> XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX, major:0, minor:1, proximity:2 +/- 0.32m, rssi:-49)
```

in this value i want to get the proximity as `+/- 0.32m` value but then i am accessing the proximity value i am not getting it how can i access this value can anyone help me with this i am using newest `IOS SDK`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CLProximity will not tell the distance in meters
It will just give you value in

```
CLProximityUnknown,
CLProximityImmediate,
CLProximityNear,
CLProximityFar
```

To find distance in meters (for example beacon is in range of 15 meters) you need look [this](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ijitee.org%2Fattachments%2FFile%2Fv2i2%2FA0359112112.pdf&ei=8rdCUoPANo6R0QXn_4GYDA&usg=AFQjCNFjrPoiVn7e9xPV1mi55AS4E6jwpg&bvm=bv.53077864,d.d2k) document. The formula is #19 on page 3 and basically it does this:

```
Received Signal Strength is related to distance using the equation below.
RSSI [dBm] = -10n log10 (d) + A [dBm]
```

Where
**A** *is the received signal strength in dBm at 1 meter - you need to calibrate this on your system. Because you are calibrating at a known distance you don't need to take into account the frequency of your transmission and this simplifies the equation. (Just place the iBeacon to 1 meters range, and measure it's RSSI)*

**n** is *the propagation pathloss exponent i.e. 2.7 to 4.3 (Free space has n = 2 for reference, if there are walls it will be greater).*

**d** *is the distance from the sender in meters*

So you have all values, except **d**, you need to calculate **d** by using mentioned formula.

**EDIT: Accuracy**
CoreLocation also provides `accuracy` property for `CLBeacon`.
You are right it's provided in meters, but shows how accurate is the measurement.

In you case it shows that beacon proximity is CLProximityNear, and it's accurate by +/- 0.32m.

Here is documentation about `accuracy`

```
/*
 *  accuracy
 *
 *  Discussion:
 *    Represents an one sigma horizontal accuracy in meters where the measuring device's location is
 *    referenced at the beaconing device. This value is heavily subject to variations in an RF environment.
 *    A negative accuracy value indicates the proximity is unknown.
 *
 */
@property (readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationAccuracy accuracy;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer l0gg3r but when i getting the values from beacon i am seeing something like this ` proximity:2 +/- 0.32m`  in that u can see 0.32m are shown is there a way to access that value ?

Comment: @CodingISLife yes of course it's accuracy property, please see my edit.

Comment: thank you, can we build a relationship between accuracy and distance ?

Comment: all you need, to calculate distance with above formula, and +/- the accuracy.

Comment: The link seems expired @l0gg3r